# Identity Server JWT access token not coming back in full but only partial.

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm calling my connect/token endpoint that identity server provides. When I'm entering my credentials to retrieve said access token, I am only getting back a partial token this long - 123456689080192830918230912830918203810928, without any periods in between. Unsure why the identity server is spitting this back out at me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your client configuration (in the IdentityServer) when setting up clients (like [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html#defining-the-client) - defining the client section) there is an option, in the Client object: `AccessTokenType`

To see the full JWT token, this option should **NOT** be set to `AccessTokenType.Reference`

You either set it to `AccessTokenType.Jwt`, or you dont set it at all, because Jwt is the default value.

Comment: I did have AccessTokenType.Reference in my config. However when I change it to AccessTokenType.Jwt, I'm not seeing a difference.

Comment: Remove it, rebuild the solution, and most important - restart identity server or IIS (depending on your deployment). You should start a clean instance of Identity Server, so that it can take the new values.

Comment: I cleaned the solution and rebuilt it. Then started debug mode in visual studio. I'm still not seeing a difference. I'm testing locally at the moment so I don't need to push via IIS yet.

Comment: sounds weird but - try removing the AccessTokenType from the client config at all

Comment: Same result. I put some breakpoints in that function and nothing. So it's not hitting any of it apparently

Comment: So it means it is not going through there, and it is not getting the new client configuration. This explains why you see the reference token instead of JWT. Now why it is not hitting.. ? Check if you have a running dotnet.exe process in the task manager, and if so - kill it

Comment: The dotnet.exe was what I had running for this project. I have been killing it and then cleaning -> building this project. What are your thoughts on this - I'm connected to a dev DB and retrieving tables from there. I believe this config file will run once it's pushed to the dev environment. Once this happens, I should see my updates to the access token type right? Should I keep it as Reference or Jwt?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169118/discussion-between-m3n7alsnak3-and-userlkjsflkdsvm).